# LEFT function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking in an Oracle (10g) stored procedure and come across the following `LEFT`/`RIGHT`function.

```
TO_DATE(LEFT('01-Jun-1201',9))
```

In the Toad editor, I am not able to run this function and have to change it to `LPAD`

```
TO_DATE(LPAD('01-Jun-1201',9))
```

The stored procedure is running fine with `LEFT`/`RIGHT` function but it runs faster if I use `LPAD`/`RPAD`.

Is there any `LEFT` Function in Oracle and if not then why is the stored procedure running fine?

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(DECODE(SIGN(TO_DATE(LEFT('01-Jun-12', 9)) - TO_DATE(logdate)),
               -1, totaltime, 0, totaltime, 0)) AS totaltime
  FROM AREA2.v_area
  WHERE logdate >= TO_DATE(RIGHT('01-Jun-12', 9))
    AND logdate <= TO_DATE('30-Jun-12')
```

Comment: Well did you search the database, are there any functions `LEFT` ?

Comment: `LEFT` and `RIGHT` are SQL Server functions that do what `LPAD`/`RPAD` do. You may have a user-defined function in your DB, that would explain the slowdown.

Comment: @smp - .NET tags removed

Comment: Try this: `select object_name from all_objects where object_type='FUNCTION'`, and see if your `LEFT` and `RIGHT` are there.

Comment: Thanks for your messages. Yes i can find them in user-defined functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no documented LEFT() function in Oracle.  [Find the full set here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions.htm#i1482196).

Probably what you have is a user-defined function.  You can check that easily enough by querying the data dictionary:

```
select * from all_objects
where object_name = 'LEFT'
```

But there is the question of why the stored procedure works and the query doesn't.  One possible solution is that the stored procedure is owned by another schema, which also owns the LEFT() function.  They have granted rights on the procedure but not its dependencies.  This works because  stored procedures run with DEFINER privileges by default, so you run the stored procedure as if you were its owner.

If this is so then the data dictionary query I listed above won't help you: it will only return rows for objects you have rights on.  In which case you will need to run the query as the stored procedure's owner or connect as a user with the rights to query DBA_OBJECTS instead.

Comment: Yes LEFT/RIGHT is a user defined function and they can be accessed with user name. SELECT TO_DATE(TS.LEFT('01-Jun-1201',9)) FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 38):

I've discovered that LEFT and RIGHT are not supported functions in Oracle. They are used in SQL Server, MySQL, and some other versions of SQL. In Oracle, you need to use the SUBSTR function. Here are simple examples:

```
LEFT ('Data', 2) = 'Da'

->   SUBSTR('Data',1,2) = 'Da'

RIGHT ('Data', 2) = 'ta'

->   SUBSTR('Data',-2,2) = 'ta'
```

Notice that a negative number counts back from the end.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT is not a function in Oracle. This probably came from someone familiar with [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql):

> Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number of characters.

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse  
LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--LEFT FUNCTION
create or replace function LEFT(value in varchar2,part in int) return varchar2 is
wreturn varchar2(500);
begin
select substr(value,1,part) into wreturn from dual;
return wreturn;
end;



--RIGHT FUNCTION
create or replace function RIGHT(value in varchar2,part in int) return varchar2 is
wreturn varchar2(500);
begin
select substr(reverse(value),1,part) into wreturn from dual;
return wreturn;
end;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add a couple of words to make clear how the code relates to the question.